# JavaScript function call failing when made from Wicket Java

Tags: java, javascript, wicket

I am facing a trouble with a call to JavaScript from Wicket Java code. I have a form with two text fields, one button and one hidden field. I want to concatenate the texts of the text fields and set that concatenated text to the hidden field when that button is clicked, using JavaScript.

Here is my code:

Java:

```
Form form = new Form("field");
form.setOutputMarkupId(true);


TextField textField1 = new TextField("field1");
textField1.setOutputMarkupId(true);
form.add(textField1);

TextField textField2 = new TextField("field2");
textField2.setOutputMarkupId(true);
form.add(textField2);

HiddenField hiddenField = new HiddenField("hiddenField");
hiddenField.setOutputMarkupId(true);
form.add(hiddenField);

Button concatButton = new Button("concat");
concatButton.add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("onclick", "concat"));
form.add(concatButton);
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="javascript">
    function concat() {
        var val1=document.getElementById("field1").value;
        var val2=document.getElementById("field2").value;
        document.getElementById("hiddenField").value=val1+val2;         
    }
</script>
```

But it is not working. Any information will be very helpful to me. Thank you.
Note: I have also tried `AjaxSubmitButton`, but that was giving me an error.

Comment: 1) Please format your code properly 2) Without seeing the source HTML that Wicket is generating this is impossible to answer.

Comment: can you show us the generated html?

Comment: Why do you need this? What's the actual problem you want to solve? Wicket probably has a much more efficient way of achieving what you want.

Comment: This is my HTML code: 
<form wicket:id="field">
 <input wicket:id="field1" />
 <input wicket:id="field2" />
 <input type="hidden" wicket:id="hiddenField" />
 <input type="button" wicket:id="concat" />
</form>
In my first post I have tried to show this code, but the html was not displaying.

Comment: well your javascript function doesn't work as none of your form elements have ids - what you are passing to the Wicket constructors is a wicket:id. See tetsuo's answer on how to change this behaviour.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TextField.setOutputMarkupId()` will make the component to print the `id` attribute, but the id attribute is not, by default, the same as the component id (the first String parameter you always pass in the constructor), but a generated one.

Try this:

```
textField1.setMarkupId("field1");
textField2.setMarkupId("field2");
hiddenField.setMarkupId("hiddenField");
```

And, if you don't use the TextFields' values on the server-side (only the hiddenField value), you could also not add them as Wicket components at all, and leave them just as static HTML (with fixed ids).

**[Edited to improve clarity through an example]**

Another option is to generate the script (or the call to a function), using the generated IDs:

HomePage.java

```
public class HomePage extends WebPage {
    public HomePage() {
        Component field1 = new TextField("field1").setOutputMarkupId(true);
        Component field2 = new TextField("field2").setOutputMarkupId(true);
        Component hidden = new HiddenField("hidden").setOutputMarkupId(true);

        String script = String.format("concatValues('%s','%s','%s');",
                field1.getMarkupId(), field2.getMarkupId(), hidden.getMarkupId());
        Component concat = new Button("concat").add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("onclick", script));

        Component show = new Button("show").add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("onclick",
            String.format("alert(document.getElementById('%s').value);", hidden.getMarkupId())));

        add(new Form("form").add(field1, field2, hidden, concat, show));
    }
}
```

HomePage.html

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
function concatValues(field1Id, field2Id, hiddenId) {
  document.getElementById(hiddenId).value = document.getElementById(field1Id).value + document.getElementById(field2Id).value;
}
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form wicket:id="form">
    <input wicket:id="field1">
    <input wicket:id="field2">
    <input wicket:id="hidden" type="hidden">
    <input wicket:id="concat" type="button" value="Concat">
    <input wicket:id="show" type="button" value="Show hidden value">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, an example to do this with Ajax (the concat operation is done on the server, not in javascript):

HomePage.java

```
public class HomePage extends WebPage {
    String field1;
    String field2;
    String hidden;
    public HomePage() {
        Form form = new Form("form", new CompoundPropertyModel(this));
        form.add(new TextField("field1"));
        form.add(new TextField("field2"));
        form.add(new HiddenField("hidden"));
        form.add(new AjaxButton("concat") {
            @Override
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
                hidden = field1 + field2;
                target.addComponent(form);
            }
        });
        form.add(new AjaxButton("show") {
            @Override
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
                target.appendJavascript("alert('" + JavascriptUtils.escapeQuotes(hidden) + "')");
            }
        });
        add(form);
    }
}
```

HomePage.html

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<body>
  <form wicket:id="form">
    <input wicket:id="field1">
    <input wicket:id="field2">
    <input wicket:id="hidden" type="hidden">
    <input wicket:id="concat" type="button" value="Concat">
    <input wicket:id="show" type="button" value="Show hidden value">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could do it somewhat the other way and publish this somewhat like faith mentions below, but you'll have to use the markup ids to do this from java. (i.e. SimpleAttributeModifier("onclick",insert javascript here replacing field1, field2, and hiddenField with textField1.getMarkupId(), textField2.getMarkupId(), hiddenField.getMarkUpId().) They'll most likely be something like field1_1 or something that includes field1, but rarely will it be just field1.

Comment: Well, I've tried to say that with "concatenating the generated IDs into the script". Not clear enough, it seems

Comment: Thank you. By following the first procedure I am getting this error :

This component is not (yet) coupled to a page. It has to be able to find the page it is supposed to operate in before you can call this method (Component#getMarkupId)

Comment: Strange, it did work for me. Well, you may try to change the order of the instructions, adding the form and fields before generating the script and adding the buttons...

Comment: Yes it is working if I made a single page as above but in my case it is different. I have to add that form withing a fragment of a panel. The answer I gave in below.

Answer (score 0):

```
new SimpleAttributeModifier("onclick", "concat();")
```

or

```
link.add(new AttributeAppender("onclick", new Model("concat();"), ";"));
```

better to do like below

https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/calling-javascript-function-on-wicket-components-onclick.html

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem this way as none of the above procedure is working in my case, this is perhaps due to the structure of my page:

```
                TextField textField1 = new TextField("field1");
                textField1.setOutputMarkupId(true);
                textField1.setMarkupId("field1");

                TextField textField2 = new TextField("field2");
                textField2.setOutputMarkupId(true);
                textField2.setMarkupId("field2");

                HiddenField hiddenField = new HiddenField("hidden");
                hiddenField.setOutputMarkupId(true);
                hiddenField.setMarkupId("hiddenField");


                String function = "document.getElementById('"+ hiddenField.getMarkupId() +"').value = document.getElementById('"+ textField1.getMarkupId() +"').value + ' ' + document.getElementById('"+ textField2.getMarkupId() +"').value;";
                Button concatButton = new Button("concat");
                concatButton.add(new AttributeAppender("onclick", new Model(function), ";"));
```

And it worked. Thanks for helping me.